# Random Forest Feature Importance Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, random-forest, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to get the feature importance from my data after performing hyperparameter tuning and getting the best parameters for my classifier. I have also fitted my best parameters to the training set and now I am trying to get the important features but I keep getting errors and have tried every possible solution I found on the internet.

View my code below;

```
enter code here
# define models and parameters for hyperparametrs
from sklearn.experimental import enable_halving_search_cv  
from sklearn.model_selection import HalvingGridSearchCV

# define grid search

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
# Create the parameter grid based on the results of random search 
param_grid = {
    'bootstrap': [True],
    'max_features': ['auto','sqrt'],
    'n_estimators': [100,1000]
}


# Create a based model
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
# Instantiate the grid search model
grid_search = HalvingGridSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_grid = param_grid, 
                          cv = 3, n_jobs = -1, verbose = 2)
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle = True, random_state=42)



steps_3 = [('over', RandomOverSampler()),  ('chi_square', SelectKBest(chi2, k=7000)), ('estimator', grid_search)]
pipeline_3 = Pipeline(steps=steps_3)
#fit the model
rf_hyperparameter = pipeline_3.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(rf_hyperparameter)

# print('Best parameter set: %s' % grid_search.best_params_)
print("Best Score:" + str(grid_search.best_score_))
print("Best Parameters: " + str(grid_search.best_params_))
best_parameters = grid_search.best_params_

#fit the best parameters to the training data
rf_best = RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap = True, max_features= 'auto', n_estimators = 1000)
rf_best.fit(X_train, y_train)

feature_importances = pd.DataFrame(rf_best.feature_importances_, 
                                   index=X_train.columns,columns=['importance']).sort_values('importance',ascending = False)
feature_importances
```

After running the above code, this is the error I get

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-159-563c7c3e7fc5> in <module>
      1 feature_importances = pd.DataFrame(rf_best.feature_importances_, 
----> 2                                    index=X_train.columns,columns=['importance']).sort_values('importance',ascending = False)
      3 feature_importances

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

I will really appreciate any input I can get. Thanks!

Comment: The part of the code where `train_test_split` is done is missing, could you add it

Comment: Yes. See the part here. #Split Train and Test Data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42,stratify=Y)

Answer (score 0):

The part of the code where `train_test_split` is done is missing from question. The `train_test_split` returns `numpy` array and not pandas dataframe, hence `X_train.columns` will fail. Taking the `df.columns` from the pandas dataframe itself as a `list` and passing in `index` should work.